# How to subscribe to primeNg event

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using angular 2 and primeng 2.0.0 and working with their DataTable
component. I want to subscribe to `onColumnResizeEnd()` in my component.

How can I subscribe to the event? I tried to subscribe as usual but I don't have the event parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can subscribe to the event like below:

```
<p-dataTable (onColResize)="someFuncInComponent($event)" />
```